# Html/CSS issue with background sizing

Tags: html, css, image, resize

Alright so i have been having a hard time when applying background image to my html code. The problem is that if i make my browser too big it will zoom in too much and if the window is too small it will cut off half of the website. I want to figure out a way to make it so that whenever i resize the browser window the background would also resize depending on the browser window size.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `background-size:contain;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS has a background-size property that you can set.

`background-size: contain;` would probably do the trick.

Below are some more resources regarding hte CSS property background-size.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

contain is most likely what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! That works, but it leaves a lot of white space. Is there a way to fix that or is it because my bg needs to be bigger?